# How to sort a matrix (or vector) in Matlab without repetitive elements? (How to Distinct Sort)

Tags: matlab, sorting

How to sort a matrix (or vector) in Matlab without repetitive elements? (How to Distinct Sort?)

Comment: I think this adds to the findability of the solution on Stack Overflow. (Note that if you actually use google to search for `matlab distinct sort`, you would already find the solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you seem to be looking for is getting a sorted list of unique values.

This can be done with `unique`

```
x=[1 2 3 3 2 1 0 1]
unique(x)
```

Will result in:

```
[0 1 2 3]
```